# Can Drupal send password reset tokens to non-default emails for accounts?

Tags: drupal, authentication, sso

**Can Drupal send password reset tokens to email addresses other than the Primary in the linked CiviCRM contact?**

If this question veers too far away from CiviCRM, I apologize. This ability might permit resetting passwords for all users in our Active Directory Federated Services/Office 365 environment - a huge benefit!

We are migrating away from a CRM we can't afford. We had a custom web application resetting AD passwords by searching the old CRM's email database and generating a link for the associated user, who could have any number of emails associated. The big problem is that the **Primary email is likely issued by us** via Office 365 and thus uses the same AD FS credentials that we would like to sync Drupal to. (We have achieved SSO everywhere else and don't want Drupal/CiviCRM to be separate.) Therefore, someone needing a password reset probably can't access his/her Primary email, either.

As the trend is lately, we allow students access to .edu emails after graduation, so we have quite a few random people out there forgetting passwords. A very desirable side effect of using CiviCRM for password resets is that alumni will probably care a lot more about keeping their own contact information up-to-date with us (since access to their .edu email depends on it).

If I can send password reset tokens to any one of a contact's emails, a lot of problems are suddenly solved.

Comment: Am not familiar with ADFS, but do you need a drupal reset link or an ADFS reset link?

Comment: ADFS doesn't have rest links per se. It's just a link between Azure's servers and a local domain controller.

Comment: According to discussions I've read online, Drupal LDAP can write back changes to AD if desired (the default is read-only). That would allow Drupal to change AD passwords.

The previous comment was submitted accidentally - didn't use Shift+Enter.

Answer (score 1):

This is not default. It's a custom drupal module or a custom CiviCRM extension, depending on the exact use case. Should not be that difficult.

Comment: Thank you. I just found a relevant question at the Drupal Stack Exchange: [Would Drupal send to an alternative email address for reset password?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/170109/would-drupal-send-to-an-alternative-email-address-for-reset-password). The answer there says I need to implement hook_mail_alter(), where I could add additional emails. I might try and make a module to do this.